# RallyDev - Requesting List of Iterations for a Users DefaultProject

Tags: web-services, rest, rally

Using the RallyDev Web Services API v2.0 I would like to request the iterations for a users default project.

I can do this now by first calling:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/iteration:current?pretty=true
```

Parsing out Iteration->Project->Ref, and then calling calling:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/[ProjectID]/Iterations?pretty=true
or
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/iteration?query=(Project.Oid=[ProjectID])&pretty=true
```

Wondering if there is a better way?

I saw [UserProfile](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/objectModel.sp#UserProfile) had DefaultProject and DefaultWorkspace, but I couldn't figure out how to use them as fetching just returned 'null'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your queries on Iteration are spot on for looking up Iterations for a particular Project. Note that for [UserProfile](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/objectModel.sp#UserProfile) - the Default Workspace/Project settings are not required fields. They are empty unless the User has explicitly set these in his or her profile settings. Only the user him/herself can set these - a (Workspace/Subscription) Administrator cannot set them on behalf of the User. So if you're getting empty values back for these, it is likely because the User of concern does not have the Default Workspace/Project set.

Comment: Well this teaches me something about UserProfile defaults which makes sense and tells me I was doing it the best way I can. Thanks Mark.